# How do I switch my input default dictionary to lower case for NLTK comparison in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I have a python dict that looks like:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'RT': 1, u'be': 1, u'uniforms': 1, u'@ProFootballWkly:': 1, u'in': 1, u'Nike': 1, u'Brooklyn.': 1, u'ET': 1, u"NFL's": 1, u'will': 1, u'a.m.': 1, u'at': 1, u'unveiled': 1, u'Jimmy': 3, u'11': 1, u'new': 1, u'The': 2, u'today': 1})
```

I'm processing it with:

```
freq_distribution = nltk.FreqDist(filtered_words)               
top_words = freq_distribution.keys()[:4]     
print top_words
```

This outputs the top 4 words which includes the word "The" I am trying to incorporate removal of Dolch "commonly used" words before this process happens with:

```
filtered_words = [w for w in word_count \
              if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
```

The problem is that I still end up with the word "The" because all of the (stopwords) from NLTK are lowercase. I need a way to take the input of word_count and switch it to lower case. I have tried adding lower() in various areas such as:

```
freq_distribution = nltk.FreqDist(word_count.lower())
```

But have not had any success, as I repeatedly get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filtered_words = [w for w in word_count \
          if w.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

This lowercases `w` *before* checking whether it's in the stopwords list.  So if `w` is "The", it will be transformed to `the` before checking.  Since "the" is in the list, it will get filtered out.

Comment: This is definitely a good answer and should solve op's problem.  In my opinion it would be more readable to do `w.lower() not in` instead of `not w.lower() in` but that is clearly very minor, just thought I would mention it.

Comment: @Nolen, Yep, I just copied and pasted from the original.  But the edit is a good idea.